# How to get array element by category?

Tags: angularjs, json, filter

I have an array of multiple products

```
var productList = [
    {
        id: '1',
        category: 'todos',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-1-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-1-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        category: 'comids',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        category: 'alcoholicas',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-1-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-1-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        category: 'no-alcoholicas',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        category: 'golosinas',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-1-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-1-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '6',
        category: 'snacks',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '7',
        category: 'cigarros',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-1-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-1-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '8',
        category: 'lacteos-y-embutidos',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '9',
        category: 'todos',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    }
];
```

Please check that there is two products which category is **todos** . So can anyone please tell me how can I get that two same category products by angularjs

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: You want to grouping product list by cagegory or you just want filter array with category `todos` ?

Comment: @Kishore Patra : Refer my answer, i have did what you want exact.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```js
var productList = [
    {
        id: '1',
        category: 'todos',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-1-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-1-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        category: 'comids',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        category: 'alcoholicas',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-1-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-1-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        category: 'no-alcoholicas',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        category: 'golosinas',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-1-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-1-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '6',
        category: 'snacks',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '7',
        category: 'cigarros',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-1-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-1-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '8',
        category: 'lacteos-y-embutidos',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: '9',
        category: 'todos',
        menuName: 'Empanada de Carne, Pollo o Mixta + Café 8oz.',
        menuPrice: '9.99',
        description: 'Panceta de cerdo sancochada y luego frita, acompañada de guarnición de mote y habas sancochadas (puspu), papas nativas doradas con cascara y sal de Maras, sarsa de cebolla con hierba buena; típicas guarniciones que acompañan el chicharrón y la infaltable uchucuta a base de rocoto y huacatay.',
        smallImage: 'product-2-191x191.jpg',
        bigImage: 'product-2-382x382.jpg'
    }
];
var temp = [];
angular.forEach(productList, function(element) {
if (element.category === 'todos') {
                     
                      temp.push(element)
                    }
  
});
console.log(temp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is simply can be done using javascript only using for loop like this try this code

```
var duplicate = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < this.productList.length ; i++){
  if(this.productList[i].category === 'todos'){
    this.duplicate.push(this.productList[i]);   //push only object having category naed todos
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:-

Use a filter with category `todos`

```
var todosList = $filter('filter')(productList, function (p) {
    return p.category === 'todos';
});
```

Comment: you should mark accepted to one answer, for people who will be searching for similar kind of questions